# Group list by values and keep both

Tags: python

I have a list which contains tuple pairs of xy-points(as tuples). The first one represents an arbitrary point and the second one the centroid of a cluster which is the nearest neighbour to that point.

```
all_neighbours = 
[((28, 145), (25, 125)), ((65, 140), (44, 105)), ((50, 130), (25, 125)), 
 ((38, 115), (44, 105)), ((55, 118), (44, 105)), ((50, 90),  (44, 105)), 
 ((63, 88 ), (44, 105)), ((43, 83 ), (29, 97 )), ((50, 60),  (55, 63 )),
 ((50, 30 ), (55, 20 ))]
```

I want to create a new list which will contain the new neigbourhoud/cluster created by these point-nearest neighbour tuples. Something like that(or having tuples grouping the points instead of lists):

```
[[(55, 20), (50, 30)], [(25, 125), (28, 145), (50, 130)], 
 [(44, 105), (65, 140), (38, 115), (55, 118), (50, 90), (63, 88)],
 [(55, 63), (50, 60)], [(29, 97),  (43, 83)]]
```

I have tried doing this by:

```
centroids = set(map(lambda x: x[1], all_neighbours))
neighbourhood = [(x, [y[0] for y in all_neighbours if y[1] == x]) for x in centroids]
>>
[((55, 20), [(50, 30)]), ((25, 125), [(28, 145), (50, 130)]),
 ((44, 105), [(65, 140), (38, 115), (55, 118), (50, 90), (63, 88)]),
 ((55, 63), [(50, 60)]), ((29, 97), [(43, 83)])]
```

But of course it didn't  produce the result I wanted.
Is there a way to get this done in a more pythonic way(than bellow)?

---

I know it can be done with another iteration:

```
neighbourhood = [[y[0] for y in all_neighbours if y[1] == x] for x in centroids]

for neigh,cent in zip(neighbourhood, centroids):
    neigh.append(cent)
```

Comment: You want to group the points by their centroids where the centroid is item one of each tuple?

Comment: the centroid is item two of each tuple(many points can be assigned to the same centroid). I can already group them but cannot get the form I need(basically express neighbouhoods and not relations). Isn't that clear in the question?

Comment: Please post the expected result for your example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator, itertools
all_neighbours = [((28, 145), (25, 125)), ((65, 140), (44, 105)),
                  ((50, 130), (25, 125)), ((38, 115), (44, 105)),
                  ((55, 118), (44, 105)), ((50, 90),  (44, 105)),
                  ((63, 88 ), (44, 105)), ((43, 83 ), (29, 97 )),
                  ((50, 60),  (55, 63 )), ((50, 30 ), (55, 20 ))]
```

Sort the list by the centroids-

```
centroid = operator.itemgetter(1)
point = operator.itemgetter(0)

all_neighbours.sort(key = centroid)
```

Use `itertools.groupby` to produce the groups

```
for centre, points in itertools.groupby(all_neighbours, centroid):
    print tuple([centre] + map(point, points))

neighbourhoods = [tuple([centre] + map(point, points)) for centre, points
                  in itertools.groupby(all_neighbours, centroid)]
```

Comment: I have already managed to produce this result as you can see on my question. I want for example `((25, 125), [(28, 145), (50, 130)])` to be `((25, 125), (28, 145), (50, 130))`. Though this is a nice approach